# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.datasets.mldata'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying the following snippet:

```
from sklearn.datasets.mldata import fetch_mldata
```

However, I get the error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.datasets.mldata'

Then I tried to figure out the problem:

[image]

Can you identify the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sklearn.datasets.mldata module was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in version 0.22. You can use the `from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml` function instead.

For more information, see the sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml documentation:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml.html

Comment: import sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml()                                                            
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'fetch_mldata' from 'sklearn.datasets' (<env path>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py)

Comment: Sorry I think it's actually from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import from the wrong module. `from sklearn.datasets import fetch_ml`

See: https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_mldata.html

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'fetch_mldata' from 'sklearn.datasets' (<env path>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py)